# FormData in AJAX is not known to my php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form called *thumbnail* with enctype in it and method POST. But the data returning from my PHP isn't recognizing my AJAX. My PHP is supposed to insert the values of the form into a MySQL database, but whenever I submit the form I get: `uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'QuizTitle' cannot be null`. The form works when I assign the values manually in the ajax like: "&nameOfProperty=" + $("#idOfTheProperty").val(). But for some reason, it's not working with FormData. I suspect that the problem is somewhere in the AJAX, but I'm not sure where. This happens with all the forms that have FormData in my code. I also have processType and contentType, which are needed for formData.

My PHP:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(25);

                   $sql  = "
                        INSERT INTO Quizzes
                            (QuizMaker, DateCreated, Rating, RatingComments, AverageScore, Difficulty, AverageTimeTaken, Views, Likes, Dislikes, LikesToDislikePercentage, QuizTitle, QuizDescription, QuizThumbnail, OneByOne, Public, PremiumQuiz, QuizBundler, ScrambleOptions, ScrambleQuestions, FontSize, QuizTrackingId)
                        VALUES
                            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                    ";
                    $query = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ssisiiiiiiissbssssssis", $_SESSION['usernameId'], $dateTimeVariable, $na, $na, $na, $na, $na, $na, $na, $na, $na, $_POST['QuizTitle'], $_POST['QuizDescription'], $imageQuizThumbnail, $_POST['OneByOne'], $_POST['Public'], $_POST['PremiumQuiz'], $_POST['QuizBundler'], $_POST['ScrambleOptions'], $_POST['ScrambleQuestions'], $fontSize, $bytes);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);

                    $sql0 = "INSERT INTO Genre (Genre, QuizTrackingId) VALUES (?, ?)";
                    $query0 = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql0);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query0, "ss", $_POST['Genre'], $bytes);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($query0);
                    $result0 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query0);
```

Form:

```html
<form id="thumbnail" action="jhyric7b34yub57iybiuyur3u85iofh8.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p id="thumb">Thumbnail:</p>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quizTitle" name="QuizTitle" placeholder="Quiz Title" required>
  <textarea placeholder="Quiz Description" id="quizDescription" name="QuizDescription" required></textarea>
  <br>
  <div>
    <label for="genre">Genre</label>
    <input type="text" list="genre" name="Genre" id="genreBox" required>
    <datalist id="genre">
      <option>Writing/Language</option>
      <option>Foreign Languages</option>
      <option>Math</option>
      <option>Science</option>
      <option>Fantasy</option>
      <option>Sci-fi</option>
      <option>Mystery</option>
      <option>Movies/Songs/Games/TV Shows</option>
      <option>Entertainment</option>
      <option>Mixed</option>
      <option>Social Studies</option>
      <option>General Knowledge</option>
      <option>History</option>
      <option>Books</option>
      <option>Fiction</option>
      <option>Items</option>
      <option>Geography</option>
      <option>Space</option>
      <option>People</option>
      <option>Sports</option>
      <option>Outdoors</option>
      <option>Other</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label for="image" class="custom-file-upload">Add a Thumbnail Image:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="QuizThumbnail" id="image" accept="image/*" required>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input layout" id="customSwitch3" name="OneByOne" checked>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch3" id="customSwitch3Label">One by One.</label>
    <i id="bla" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
      title="Hosts can change this. One By One means that the Quizzes will appear after the player completes a question. While unchecking it, will let the player do all the Questions(without the background images) all in one page."
      height="16px">
    </i>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input layout" id="customSwitch4" name="Public" checked>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch4" id="customSwitch4Label">Public.</label>
    <i id="bla" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
      title="If checked, anyone can view it. If not checked, only people with the link can view it." height="16px">
    </i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="bundle">Want To bundle The Quiz?</label>
    <datalist id="bundle">
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 1</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 2</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 3</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 4</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 5</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 6</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 7</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 8</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 9</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 10</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 11</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 12</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 13</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 14</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 15</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 16</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 17</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 18</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 19</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 20</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 21</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 22</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 23</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 24</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 25</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 26</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 27</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 28</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 29</option>
      <option>Past Quiz 30</option>
    </datalist>
    <input type="text" name="QuizBundler" list="bundle">
    <i id="exy" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
      title="For Premium users." height="16px">
    </i>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch5" name="ScrambleOptions">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch5">Scramble Options</label>
    <i id="bla" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
      title="Hosts can change this." height="16px">
    </i>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch6" name="ScrambleQuestions">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch6">Scramble Questions</label>
    <i id="bla" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
      title="Hosts can change this." height="16px">
    </i>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Font Size</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="16">16</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="18">18</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="20">20</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" id="22">22</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Your font size is <span id="fontSizeSpan">
      <input type="text" readonly style="border: none;" name="FontSize" id="realFontSize" placeholder="normal.">
    </span>
  </p>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1" name="PremiumQuiz">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Premium User Quiz</label>
    <i id="exy" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle info premium" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
      title="If checked, then only Premium Players can play the quiz. For Premium Users." height="16px">
    </i>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
var tnv = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
                  var thumbnail = new FormData(tnv);
                  $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "jhyric7b34yub57iybiuyur3u85iofh8.php",
                          data: {thumbnail},
                          cache: false,
                          contentType: false,
                          processData: false
                      }) .done(function(Created) {
                          alert(Created);
                       }) .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                          alert("Woah");
                  })
                    
                 $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "jhyric7b34yub57iybiuyur3u85iofh8.php",
                          data: "Genre=" + $("#genreBox").val(),
                          cache: false,
                          contentType: false,
                          processData: false
                      }) .done(function(Created) {
                          alert(Created);
                       }) .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                          alert("Woah");
                  })
```

Comment: Don't wrap the FormData object in `{}` when you pass it to `data`. Should just be `data: thumbnail `

Comment: It still gives the same notice

Comment: Did you remove the second ajax?

Comment: Which second Ajax

Comment: You have two `$.ajax()` in the question code

Comment: Now I get an error of unable to upload file permission denied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239897/discussion-between-pal-dhillon-and-charlietfl).